# Repeated down times with connection timed out issue

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, connection, database-connection, connectivity

I hosted WordPress site on AWS,but the problem is I am getting repeated down times with the error "CONNECTION TIMED OUT".

The error CONNECTION TIMED OUT is being resolved after rebooting the instance

Is there a permanent solution to connection timed out errors?? other than rebooting every now and then

TIA

I rebooted and site is live from down state.

But it goes down every day for 3-4 times for which I have to reboot every time.

Comment: It sounds like the WordPress/PHP app is crashing, and a reboot of the server is also restarting the app. Or possibly you have a burstable T* instance type that is running out of CPU credits. The "CONNECTION TIMED OUT" error is just a symptom of the actual problem, and you need to determine what the actual problem is before you can solve it.

Comment: [Error logging for WordPress](https://wordpress.com/go/tutorials/set-up-wordpress-error-logs/) may be helpful.